# move Hyper-V VM to new server withn the same domain name

Tags: virtual-machine, hyper-v

We have a windows server 2008 work as domain controller and running Hyper-V. There are 2 Hyper-V vm in old one. They all join the domain.

Now we have a new server windows server 2012 as domain control and set the same domain name as old one.

If we move the VM to new one. Will they work as domain member  within new one? Or we need leave from old one ,move to new one then join domain again?

If need join again How about the files under AD account?  Will be lost or not. The program and other setting will work fine or need reinstall or reset?

Comment: Just to clarify, as I believe my answer which I have temporarily removed may be incorrect depending on your answer. Was your new domain controller added to the existing domain, or is it a remake of the old domain?

Answer (score 1):

Moving a VM to another host is exactly the same as moving a physical server to another room – its files, its OS configuration, etc. are *not* related to the host at all, and remain the same after moving.

Thus VMs' domain membership will not be affected.

---

However, you must also set up the *domain controller* correctly. It's **not enough** to just create a new domain with the same name, because it will have different security IDs.

Instead, the new server must **join** the old domain as a member. Then, if you want, it can be promoted to a domain controller using `dcpromo`, and the old server demoted.

(Though wouldn't it be better to keep AD DC and HyperV on separate servers instead? HyperV works just fine on a domain member server.)

Comment: the vm joined domain in winserver08,  now it move to winserver2012. the two server use the same domain name. will vm become  a member of winserver2012 domain without do anything?

Comment: @James Did you create the domain on winserver2012, or did you join it to winserver08's domain?

Comment: now the vm is running on server08 and join domain aa.com (server08 is domain controller).  server2012 is domain controller too and domain name is aa.com same as server2008. I want to know if i copy vm to server2012 and run. Will it  become a member of winserver2012 domain?

Comment: @James: It's **not enough** for the domain names to match. The new server must first **join the old domain**, and then be promoted to "domain controller" (dcpromo). But if you created two separate domains with identical names, they're still _separate_ domains, and members will not magically move from one domain to another.

Comment: So if i join vm to new domain. the old domain'suser folder will be overwrite by new server's (because they are using same domain name ) or new one will create another userfolder and i have to  migrate old one to new one.  Many thanks for you help!!

Comment: No, it won't be overwritten – Windows will always create a new folder for a new user (even if the names are the same, it'll use James.MYDOMAIN, James.MYDOMAIN1, etc.) – but you won't be able to access it unless you `takeown` and reset permissions.